# Select a valid choice. ['FRI'] is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django

I want a multiple select field in my django form. It does not save the values in database.

models.py

```
DAYS=(
('*', 'All'),
('MON', 'Monday'),
('TUE', 'Tuesday'),
('WED', 'Wednesday'),
('THU', 'Thursday'),
('FRI', 'Friday'),
('SAT', 'Saturday'),
('SUN', 'Sunday'),
)

game_day = models.CharField(max_length = 200, choices = DAYS)
```

forms.py

```
DAY_OF_WEEK=(
('*', 'All'),
('MON', 'Monday'),
('TUE', 'Tuesday'),
('WED', 'Wednesday'),
('THU', 'Thursday'),
('FRI', 'Friday'),
('SAT', 'Saturday'),
('SUN', 'Sunday'),
)

game_day = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=DAY_OF_WEEK, required=True, label='Game Day')
```

When I click on submit it gives the error:

Select a valid choice. ['FRI'] is not one of the available choices.

Comment: could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: There's no stack trace , Its the server side validation message being thrown.

Comment: your modelfield is charfield, and what you are trying to save is a list, like ['SUN', 'FRI']..That's what triggering the error.. You may need to change the form field to **forms.ChoiceField**...

Comment: CharField cannot accomodate a list.. Either change your form field, ie, change it ChoiceField for single choices, or change your database column..

Comment: charField is in my models file and models object has no attribute ChoiceField

Comment: I want this field to be multiple choice field not single choice field.. Then how can I change my database column to accept a list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145369/discussion-between-manpreet-ahluwalia-and-fazil-zaid).

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about how you are going to store the data at a database level.

Presumably, you want a single column in a table that is storing multiple values. This will also force you to think about how you will serialize it.

You might find these useful for your case:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-select-multiple-field/
- https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1200/

**Usually you want to store multiple choices as a manytomany link to another table.** Sometimes however it is useful to store them in the model itself. The above fields implements a model field and an accompanying formfield to store multiple choices as a comma-separated list of values, using the normal CHOICES attribute.

Comment: Actually if I remove " choices = DAYS " from my models char field it saves the list in the database . But in that case it does not pre select the item in my edit page.